# Searching for a paper on CMS Spread Option normal model price formula

Tags: spread-options, cms

Apparently if we assume that each underlying CMS rate is normally distributed then a formula for the CMS Spread Option price can be evaluated analytically in the absence of any contingency due to the fact that the difference in two normally-distributed random variables is also normally distributed. However, wherever I search I only find information on lognormal models. Please, can anyone point me to a paper or publication on this subject?

Comment: I found https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2686998, section 3 quite useful for a simple, concrete and concise approach to this.

Comment: @user35980 Thank you, this paper is indeed useful. However the author mentions two methods for the convexity adjustment to get the rate drifts right but doesn’t actually include details on how to do that. Is there any other source that covers this aspect for the normal model?

Comment: I think u can find that in his reference, Brigo/Mercurio. But note that the convexity adj for the cms rates is done independently of what he's talking about which is the valuation of the spread option - the convexity adj rates are simply used in the drifts of the two processes he is dealing with. How they are done is a separate topic.

Comment: Or take a look at Andersen, Piterbarg, Interest Rate Modeling, section 16.3.2 which goes into detail of the latest and greatest way of modeling cms convexity adj using terminal swap rate models.